# Calculating Costs Based on Dropdown List

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file that has 2 sheets. 1 for tracking services rendered and another with a list of customers and their fees per service.

**Tracking Sheet**  [See Tracking Sheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq9F6.jpg)
For each service, we manually enter a number for how many times the service was rendered. We then select the client from a drop-down list that we performed the services for.

**Clients Sheet** [See Client Sheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyDM6.jpg)

To get the "Amount Scheduled to Bill" and "Total Billed" in the tracking sheet, we reference the client sheet with pricing. This will have a list of clients along with cost for each service.

Let’s say that these are the 2 formulas that will be used to calculate the following on the tracking sheet (can probably be better and if so pls share):

Amount scheduled to be billed - (Used to calculate result for Amount Scheduled)
`=SUM(Tracking!A2*Clients!B2, Tracking!B2*Clients!C2)`

Total Billed - (Used to calculate result for Total Billed)
`=SUM(Tracking!B2* Clients!C2, Tracking!C2* Clients!D2, Tracking!D2* Clients!E2)`

**Question:**
Per row on the tracking sheet, when entering the amount of times a service was provided, how can we correlate the calculation formula per client in the drop-down to get the amount scheduled and the amount billed?

Comment: you just need to do a simple vlookup(older excel)/xlookup(newer excel versions/easier syntax). Just replace the "clients!b2" portion of your formula above with a vlookup/xlookup to pull in the correct price.

Comment: add a look up to get client and cost

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, VLOOKUP was what I needed and this [website tutorial](https://geekexcel.com/excel-formulas-vlookup-two-client-rates/).